# Remote MySQL Server not responding

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm having issues connecting to my AWS EC2 Server holding a MySQL Server.

Here's my Response from `mysqli_connect`

`p@xxx.com [~/app]# php checkmysqlremote.php
Error: Unable to connect to MySQL.
Debugging errno: 2002
Debugging error: Connection refused`

Here's my `netstat -tuplen` on the EC2 Server containing the MySQL Server

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      999        20299      1378/mysqld

As you can see its binding to the `0.0.0.0` address correctly.

I enabled the `3306 port` in inbound rules for EC2.

on the server making the request handshake, I ran:

`curl -s example.com:3306 >/dev/null && echo Success. || echo Fail.`

which resulted in `Fail.`

I also ran it on the local server instance and it responded with `Success.`

I also ran `nmap` on the server making the handshake,

`nmap -p 3306 example.com`

```
Nmap scan report for example.com (1.1.1.1)

Host is up (0.048s latency).

PORT     STATE    SERVICE

3306/tcp filtered mysql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.03 seconds
```

Lastly, I tried adding the following rules in iptables:

`iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s "example.com" -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT`

and

`sudo iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT`

I don't know what to do at this point.

**UPDATE**

I tried pinging the EC2 server from the remote server and it did not return anything. At this point i think the issue is with EC2.

Comment: user previleges on Mysql? where is the SQL server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the follwing GRANT to your user:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'ipadress'
```

Comment: maybe something with `mysql_native_password`?

Comment: i think its above the user login issue if curl is successful on the local server and not the remote server its something else maybe?

Comment: there is a firewall on the server making the request. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the port might not be getting forwarded correctly? One thing to try might be to put an Amazon Elastic Load Balancer in front of the instance. Then you can forward port 3306 for the MySQL connection.